# Combination function of array of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

If have a configuration application where a user can specify several fields to generate a form. We also have a system that stack images together. Now i need to get all possible options of the users configuration. So when i get all settings from the configuration i get this array of arrays

```
[ 
  [ 'prs', 'fctr', 'fcop' ],
  [],
  [ 'standaard', 'duimgat' ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [ 'action barrel', 'only action' ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  ['x', 'y'],
  [],
  [] 
]
```

What i now try to achieve is that i get all combinations possible from above. So for the first combination row i try to get for prs / prs_standaard / prs_duimgat / prs_standaard_action barrel / prs_standaard_only_action / prs _standaard_action barrel_x / prs_standaard_only action_ x / prs_standaard_action barrel_y / prs_standaard_only barrel_y etc

The empty arrays could be filled with data as well. This can be added dynamically by the user it self. So i try to find a combination function.

Currently i have this but it's not working correctly.

```
_createPossibleOptionsFromStackAbleImages (stackAbleImages) {
    let result = [];

    if (stackAbleImages[0] !== undefined) {
      stackAbleImages[0].forEach((bmStockModelImages) => {
        let currentIndex = result.length;
        result.push(bmStockModelImages);
        stackAbleImages.forEach((questionStackAbleImage, index) => {
          if (index === 0) { return; }
          let currentQuestionLength = questionStackAbleImage.length;
          questionStackAbleImage.forEach((stackAbleImage) => {
            result.push(`${result[currentIndex]}_${stackAbleImage}`);
          });
          currentIndex += currentQuestionLength;
        });
      });
    }

    console.log(result);

    return result;
  }
```

I only need the combinations from above to down. So i dont need x_action_barrel etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at recursion. Iterate over every array and pick every element. For the first element go to the next array and pick every element. So you call the function as long as there are more arrays to iterate. When you are done, go back one recursion step and go to the next element of the last array and so on. There are many examples on stackoverflow about javascript and recursion if you search for it.

Comment: @Urknecht. Ofcourse i forgot about recursion. Got it now thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Urknecht came with the idea to use recursion. So my last code was this.
Credits to @Urknecht for the idea

```
  static _createPossibleOptionsFromStackAbleImages (stackAbleImages) {
    let result = [];

    console.log(ConfiguratorPreLoads._makePossibleCombinations([], stackAbleImages[0], stackAbleImages, 0));

    return result;
  }

  static _makePossibleCombinations (previous, current, all, index, result = []) {
    //All possible options are checked
    if (index === all.length) {
      return result;
    }

    //Init state
    if (previous[0] === undefined) {
      current.forEach((currentValue) => {
        result.push(currentValue);
      });
      ++index;
      return ConfiguratorPreLoads._makePossibleCombinations(result, all[index], all, index, result);
    }

    //The array is empty or we are done
    if (current === undefined || current[0] === undefined) {
      ++index;
      return ConfiguratorPreLoads._makePossibleCombinations(previous, all[index], all, index, result);
    }

    //Remember the combinedPreviousValues so we can build new one from them
    let combinedPrevious = [];

    previous.forEach((previousValue) => {
      current.forEach((currentValue) => {
        combinedPrevious.push(`${previousValue}_${currentValue}`);
        result.push(`${previousValue}_${currentValue}`);
      });
    });

    index++;
    //Recursion
    return ConfiguratorPreLoads._makePossibleCombinations(combinedPrevious, all[index], all, index, result);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that you can restructure data from 2d-array to tree like this, then parse from top to bottom (^_^)

```
               __________  root ____________
              /             |               \
          __prs           fctr__          _fcop___
         /     \         /      \        /        \
  standard  duimgat standard  duimgat  standard  duimgat
  /   \     /   \   /    \    /    \   /    \    /     \
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that is hard in the current database model that i have :(